# differential split of $2$ variable problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

$d(x_1x_2)= x_1dx_2 + x_2dx_1$ as given in theory
now $\int d(x_1x_2)= \int x_1dx_2 + x_2dx_1$ 
but integrating both the sides give $x_1x_2 = 2x_1x_2 ..$ why ?
 I guess I am missing something very basic just need to know ..

Answer (score 0):

The constant..... Indefinite has this property of have various forms of answers because the remaining portion is Constant 'C'. Just like 2 is... Well, that is why it is called INDEFINITE, because you cant be pretty sure What the constant would be unless you know some more details. Does that make sense?